# WPF MessageBox close without any action

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a confirmation message box for the user in one of my apps. Below is the code for that,

```
MessageBoxResult res= System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Could not find the folder, so the D:  Drive will be opened instead.");
                if (res == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("OK");
                }
              else
                {
               MessageBox.Show("Do Nothing"); 
                }
```

Now, when the user clicks on the OK button, I want certain code to execute but when they click on the red cross at the upper right corner, I just want the messagebox to close without doing anything. In my case I get 'OK' displayed even when I click on the red cross icon at the upper right corner. Is there a way I can have 'Do Nothing' displayed when I click on the cross. I not want to add any more buttons.

Comment: Right now the only possible result is OK, but since you are actually expecting Ok/cancel input from the user, you should use Show() call with MessageBoxButton.OKCancel buttons.

Comment: so does that mean that there is no difference between clicking on the Ok button and clicking on the red cross button on the upper right corner? Doesnt red cross icon mean closing without doing anything?

Comment: In this case, no.  You are only giving the user one choice ("OK").  If you really want two paths ("OK" or "Do Nothing", i.e. "Cancel") you need to implement it that way.  That's standard Windows behavior, and to do it contrary to the "accepted" standard will be unintuitive to users of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You could make your own custom dialog form.

Comment: so does that mean that there is no difference between clicking on the Ok button and clicking on the red cross button on the upper right corner? Doesnt red cross icon mean closing without doing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a very simple way, just add the "MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel" param to your MessageBox.Show method. this way you will have two buttons (OK and Cancel). this way if the user clicks the cancel button or the red cross the DialogResult.Cancel message will be returned. the following code described the solution:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Could not find the folder, so the D:  Drive will be opened instead.", 
            "", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            MessageBox.Show("OK");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Do nothing.");
```

Comment: He doesn't want to add any more buttons.

Comment: if thats the case then as you mentioned eariler, there is no way to solve this problem.